# How do I resize the canvas in Raphael.js?

Tags: raphael

I'm having difficulty resizing the canvas in Raphael.js. I thought I could simply use:

```js
var paper = Raphael("paper", 100, 100);
```

and this would create a canvas using the ID "paper" with a width and height of 100 pixels. However when I try this the canvas doesn't initialize with these settings. I'm using some of the free icons on the Raphael.js website and I was wondering how I would change the size of the icons? Do I have to use the transform function as well? If so could somebody please create a jsfiddle example.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry if I haven't explained myself very well, but Raphael.js is completely new to me.

EDIT:

I tried your suggestions, but to no avail. Here's the code I'm working on. Maybe I have a conflict or something. Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Logo Experiment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960_16_col.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container_16">  
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div id="design"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_2">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div id="build"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_2">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4">
                <div id="deliver"></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="clear"></div>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var design = Raphael("design");
    design.path("M24.359,18.424l-2.326,1.215c0.708,1.174,1.384,2.281,1.844,3.033l2.043-1.066C25.538,20.822,24.966,19.652,24.359,18.424zM19.143,14.688c0.445,0.84,1.342,2.367,2.274,3.926l2.414-1.261c-0.872-1.769-1.72-3.458-2.087-4.122c-0.896-1.621-1.982-3.108-3.454-5.417c-1.673-2.625-3.462-5.492-4.052-4.947c-1.194,0.384,1.237,4.094,1.876,5.715C16.73,10.147,17.991,12.512,19.143,14.688zM26.457,22.673l-1.961,1.022l1.982,4.598c0,0,0.811,0.684,1.92,0.213c1.104-0.469,0.81-1.706,0.81-1.706L26.457,22.673zM24.35,15.711c0.168,0.339,2.924,5.93,2.924,5.93h1.983v-5.93H24.35zM18.34,15.704h-4.726l-3.424,5.935h11.66C21.559,21.159,18.771,16.479,18.34,15.704zM3.231,21.613l3.437-5.902H2.083v5.93h1.133L3.231,21.613zM15.048,10.145c0-0.93-0.754-1.685-1.685-1.685c-0.661,0-1.231,0.381-1.507,0.936l2.976,1.572C14.97,10.725,15.048,10.444,15.048,10.145zM14.343,12.06l-3.188-1.684L9.62,13.012l3.197,1.689L14.343,12.06zM3.192,26.886l-0.384,1.108v0.299l0.298-0.128l0.725-0.896l2.997-2.354l-3.137-1.651L3.192,26.886zM9.02,14.044l-4.757,8.17l3.23,1.706l4.728-8.186L9.02,14.044z").attr({fill: "#666", stroke: "#000"});

    var build = Raphael("build");
    build.path("M28.537,9.859c-0.473-0.259-1.127-0.252-1.609-0.523c-0.943-0.534-1.186-1.316-1.226-2.475c-2.059-2.215-5.138-4.176-9.424-4.114c-1.162,0.017-2.256-0.035-3.158,0.435c-0.258,0.354-0.004,0.516,0.288,0.599c-0.29,0.138-0.692,0.147-0.626,0.697c2.72-0.383,7.475,0.624,7.116,2.966c-0.08,0.521-0.735,1.076-1.179,1.563c-1.263,1.382-2.599,2.45-3.761,3.667l0.336,0.336c0.742-0.521,1.446-0.785,2.104-0.785c0.707,0,1.121,0.297,1.276,0.433c0.575-0.618,1.166-1.244,1.839-1.853c0.488-0.444,1.047-1.099,1.566-1.178l0.949-0.101c1.156,0.047,1.937,0.29,2.471,1.232c0.27,0.481,0.262,1.139,0.521,1.613c0.175,0.324,0.937,1.218,1.316,1.228c0.294,0.009,0.603-0.199,0.899-0.49l1.033-1.034c0.291-0.294,0.501-0.6,0.492-0.896C29.754,10.801,28.861,10.035,28.537,9.859zM13.021,15.353l-0.741-0.741c-3.139,2.643-6.52,5.738-9.531,8.589c-0.473,0.443-1.452,1.021-1.506,1.539c-0.083,0.781,0.95,1.465,1.506,2c0.556,0.533,1.212,1.602,1.994,1.51c0.509-0.043,1.095-1.029,1.544-1.502c2.255-2.374,4.664-4.976,6.883-7.509c-0.312-0.371-0.498-0.596-0.498-0.596C12.535,18.451,11.779,17.272,13.021,15.353zM20.64,15.643c-0.366-0.318-1.466,0.143-1.777-0.122c-0.311-0.266,0.171-1.259-0.061-1.455c-0.482-0.406-0.77-0.646-0.77-0.646s-0.862-0.829-2.812,0.928L7.44,6.569C7.045,6.173,7.203,4.746,7.203,4.746L3.517,2.646L2.623,3.541l2.1,3.686c0,0,1.428-0.158,1.824,0.237l7.792,7.793c-1.548,1.831-0.895,2.752-0.895,2.752s0.238,0.288,0.646,0.771c0.196,0.23,1.188-0.249,1.455,0.061c0.264,0.312-0.196,1.41,0.12,1.777c2.666,3.064,6.926,7.736,8.125,7.736c0.892,0,2.021-0.724,2.948-1.64c0.925-0.917,1.639-2.055,1.639-2.947C28.377,22.567,23.704,18.309,20.64,15.643z").attr({fill: "#666", stroke: "#000"});

    var deliver = Raphael("deliver");
    deliver.path("M17.078,22.004l-1.758-4.129l-2.007,4.752l-7.519-3.289l0.174,3.905l9.437,4.374l10.909-5.365l-0.149-4.989L17.078,22.004zM29.454,6.619L18.521,3.383l-3.006,2.671l-3.091-2.359L1.546,8.199l3.795,3.048l-3.433,5.302l10.879,4.757l2.53-5.998l2.257,5.308l11.393-5.942l-3.105-4.709L29.454,6.619zM15.277,14.579l-9.059-3.83l9.275-4.101l9.608,3.255L15.277,14.579z").attr({fill: "#666", stroke: "#000"});

    $('.arrow').each(function(i) {
        arrow = Raphael($(this)[0]);
        arrow.path("M10.129,22.186 16.316,15.999 10.129,9.812 13.665,6.276 23.389,15.999 13.665,25.725z").attr({fill: "#666", stroke: "#000"});
    });
};
```

```css
#design {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I put your code onto this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/twe7J/ so you can see the results. By the way in `$().each` you don't need to do `$(this)[0]` since this is the same thing as just putting `this` (JQuery puts a direct DOM element reference in `this` by default).

Answer (score 7):

To answer your exact question in the title, you would use `paper.setSize(width, height)`

From the Raphael docs:

[image]

Your other questions have different answers.

`var paper = Raphael("paper", 100, 100);` requires that you have some DOM element with the `id="paper"` already on your page. That DOM element should have width and height enough to hold your canvas (in this case, 100x100). Or, you can leave off the width and the height and it will take on the width and height of the container (very convenient). You can also produce a canvas without a DOM element by putting in all four dimensions, such as `var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 100, 100);` to make a 100x100 canvas at the top left of the document.

To resize the Raphael icons, you can use the transform function. For example `icon.transform("s2");` to make it twice as large.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daBT7/1/) shows how to create a Raphael canvas and put the pencil icon on it, make it yellow, and double-sized. Note that we need to scale around the top left corner (normally it scales around the center) to prevent it from clipping off the top and left of the page.

```
var pencil = "M25.31,2.872l-3.384-2.127c-0.854-0.536-1.979-0.278-2.517,0.576l-1.334,2.123l6.474,4.066l1.335-2.122C26.42,4.533,26.164,3.407,25.31,2.872zM6.555,21.786l6.474,4.066L23.581,9.054l-6.477-4.067L6.555,21.786zM5.566,26.952l-0.143,3.819l3.379-1.787l3.14-1.658l-6.246-3.925L5.566,26.952z"
var paper = Raphael(0,0,200,200);
var icon = paper.path(pencil).attr({fill: "yellow"}).transform("s2,2,0,0");
```